# Read access violation related to input(variable,anydtdtm.);

Tags: input, file-io, sas

Somebody tell me I'm not crazy. I have SAS on a server, and I'm running the following code:

```
data wtf;
    a=".123456 1 1";
    b=input(a,anydtdtm.);
run;
```

If I run this on my local computer, no problem. If I run this on the server, I get:

> ERROR:  An exception has been encountered.
> Please contact technical support and provide them with the following traceback information:
>
> The SAS task name is [DATASTEP]
>
> ERROR:  Read Access Violation DATASTEP
>
> Exception occurred at (04E0AB8C)
>
> Task Traceback
>
> Address   Frame     (DBGHELP API Version 4.0 rev 5)
>
> 0000000004E0AB8C  0000000009C4EC20  sasxdtu:tkvercn1+0x9B4C
>
> 0000000004E030D9  0000000009C4F100  sasxdtu:tkvercn1+0x2099
>
> 0000000005FF14BE  0000000009C4F108  uwianydt:tkvercn1+0x47E
>
> 0000000002438026  0000000009C4F178  tkmk:tkBoot+0x162E6

Does anyone else get this error???

Comment: Sounds like you need to submit this to SAS technical support.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal bug that cannot be resolved by the user. You'll need to send this information, your environment description, and the exact steps to recreate the bug over to SAS Technical Support to open up an investigation and determine a workaround.

If your server is a database not made up of .sas7bdat files, it might be due to the SAS/ACCESS engine attempting to translate the function into a way that the server's language can understand, but is unable to do so properly; that is, it might *think* it's doing it correctly, but it's not. There are special cases where this can occur, and you may have discovered one.

If you are in fact querying some other database, try adding this before running the data step:

`options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog;`

This will show all of the steps as SAS sends data & functions to and from the server, and may help give some insight.

Comment: I should note, I am remoting into a server with SAS on it, and running that exact code generates the error. But I see what you're saying about it being an internal bug. I'll forward it to SAS

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error on Linux system running SAS 9.4

```
AUTOMATIC SYSSCP LIN X64
AUTOMATIC SYSSCPL Linux
AUTOMATIC SYSVER 9.4
AUTOMATIC SYSVLONG 9.04.01M3P062415
AUTOMATIC SYSVLONG4 9.04.01M3P06242015
```

Until SAS can fix the informat you probably need to add additional testing in your code to exclude strange values like that.

Comment: Interesting. This must be a new bug introduced by M3. I'm running on M2 with Linux and cannot reproduce the error.